# How does hot air affect power required to move a car?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy, temperature, drag

I recently posted an answer to Sustainability StackExchange where I claimed that energy consumption for cars (specifically, for electric cars) with no air conditioning drops when it's hot. The reason being that hot air is less dense. The answer resulted in lots of scepticism judging by the downvotes.

Is this the case? Does hot air really equate to smaller resisting forces? What is the physical basis of this, and how can it be shown with laws of physics? (I'm too lazy to write an answer with details so I posted this question, hoping someone could write a detailed, clear, easy-to-understand answer.)

How much does very hot air reduce resisting forces (and thus energy consumption) when compared with freezing temperatures?

Let's assume the car has no air conditioning or that the air conditioning is turned off. Let's also ignore pressure of air in the tires, i.e. the driver adjusts the tire pressure to be always correct regardless of the temperature.

Comment: What does air conditioning have to do with it?  Presumably it's the outside air giving the resistance.  The air inside the car shouldn't be relevant, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @JMac If you run air conditioning, it requires extra energy, depleting range and using more fuel.

Comment: Just seems like a weird detail to specify.  There are a lot of factors that could in theory change the energy consumption, but if you just want to know the effect of air temperature on air resistance, for example, it would make more sense to just specify that all else is equal.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that aerodynamic drag can be characterized by the following equation

$$ F_{\rm drag} = C_{\rm drag} \left(\tfrac{1}{2}  \rho_{\rm air} A_{\rm front}  v^2 \right) $$
where $F_{\rm drag}$ is the drag force, $\rho_{\rm air}$ is the air density, $A_{\rm front}$ is the frontal area (swept area) of the vehicle, $v$ is the speed and $C_{\rm drag}$ a constant (mostly) that depends on the shape and orientation of the object.

> So yes, aerodynamic drag is directly proportional to air density.

Answer (score 0):

> I recently posted an answer to Sustainability StackExchange where I
>   claimed that energy consumption for cars (specifically, for electric
>   cars) with no air conditioning drops when it's hot. The reason being
>   that hot air is less dense.

You say the energy consumption is less in hot weather, *specifically for electric cars.* While it is true air drag is less in warm weather (as shown by @ja72) and that should reduce energy consumption (though I'm not sure how much), that would apply equally to gas engine vehicles as well, all other factors being same. So you really have to look for reasons that an electric vehicle, in particular, would have less energy consumption in cold than hot weather.

Given the above, I would look at battery efficiency as the probable reason. All batteries, including lithium ion, are less efficient at lower temperatures. You would therefore expect higher energy consumption in cold weather than hot. Another reason for higher consumption in cold weather for electrics, is heating the vehicle uses electrical energy, whereas a gas engine vehicle uses waste heat from the engine. But heating the vehicle aside, energy consumption for an electric should still be higher in cold weather than warm.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hot air reduces the density of the air upon which the gasoline engine feeds to burn its fuel. On a hot day your gasoline engine will produce significantly less power, an effect that airplane pilots have to take into consideration.

Comment: @nielsnielsen  Good point.  I was only thinking about the relative effect of air drag on energy efficiency of an electric vs gas powered vehicle, all other things being equal, since that appeared to be the focus of the OP,  as opposed to the specific effect of reduced air density on combustion efficiency. Thanks.

Comment: @nielsnielsen Did some reading on fuel economy in hot weather. All hits indicated that fuel economy increases in hot weather. The principle factors are (1) the engine warms up to an efficient temperature faster; (2)  summer grades of gasoline have slightly more energy and (3) warm air causes less aerodynamic drag than cold air. That does not mean, of course, that less dense air can adversely effect fuel economy, but since it is not cited it might not be a significant factor. I would think air density differences would be more significant for aircraft than cars.

Comment: In any case, these factors, other than air drag, don’t apply to electrics. I need to do more research, but my gut tells me battery efficiency is more important than air drag as a function of temperature for electrics

Comment: Oh, and one last thing. I would think higher air input temperature, density not withstanding, weight on the positive side for combustion efficiency.

Comment: I wonder exactly why cars are not affected by this as strongly as airplanes are!